# Data not getting updated laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to update a row in a particular table, laravel does not shows any error but value is not updating in database.

this is my update method code:

```
function update(Request $request){

  $product=product::find($request['Id']);
  $product->productName=$request['name'];
  $product->description=$request['desc'];
  $product->discount=$request['discount'];
  $product->inventory=$request['inventory'];
  $product->save();

  return response()->json(['message'=>$product->productName],200);
}
```

**I'm successfully getting all the data and I've checked that my changing the value of response json**

the variable `$product->productName` also shows updated value as it is present after `save()` method but nothing changes in database.

**The problem is with this piece of code as I have checked my model i.e product and its working fine** as `$product` *has* value.

Comment: Can you check what `$product->save();` returns?

Comment: just did this and came to know that it is returning true.

Comment: if($product->save()){

                $message="True";
                return response()->json(['message'=>$message],200);
              }

Comment: Do you have this property in your model `protected $fillable` and if so what is inside it?

Comment: no it is not
`<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class product extends Model
{
    protected $table='product';

    public function user(){

     return $this->belongsTo('App\User');

    }
}`

Comment: still not working:
`<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class product extends Model
{
    protected $table='product';
    protected $fillable = [
    'productName',
    'description',
    'discount',
    'inventory',
 ];


    public function user(){

     return $this->belongsTo('App\User');

    }


}`

Comment: Please `dd( $request->all() )` and show the results.

Comment: @MuhammadAbdullahAli you are using `save()` instead of `update()`. You may find my answer below more helpful for you to check the products and the update before returning the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you not trying to update this record?

Why are you using `save()` method, why not use `update()` since you are trying to set the given product with new set of values?:

```
 $product->update();
```

So you can finally have (suggesting a check on if a product exists and if the update was successful - you can disregard it if you like):

```
function update(Request $request)
{
      if(!$product=product::find($request['Id']))
      {
          return response()->json('Product does not exist', 404);
      }
      $product->productName=$request['name'];
      $product->description=$request['desc'];
      $product->discount=$request['discount'];
      $product->inventory=$request['inventory'];
      if($product->update())
      {
          return response()->json(['message'=>$product->productName],200);
      }

      return response()->json('Something went wrong', 500);  
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

By default Laravel is protecting all models from mass-assignment vulnerability. So you have to specify either a `$fillable` (which fields can be modified) or `$guarded` (which fields can not be modified) property.

In your case add this to the model:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'productName',
    'description',
    'discount',
    'inventory',
];
```